# How can I add a date with integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL we have two tables:

1. a table is called:"**users**" and it contains the information from members like **user_id** and **acc_type_id** which is integer and shows the number of months that an account would be expired and it contains **expiry_date** (timestamp) which shows the time that the account will be expired
2. We have another table **"account_type"** which contains **account_type_id** and **validity** which is integer(the number of months)
   Now when a user fill “users table” I want to put a trigger on insert and update:
   When the user choose acc_type_id the expiry_date will be calculated automatically with the below formula:

For example today is 2020-01-06 and they choose gold account which is 9 month (I defined it integer), so their expiry_date should be: 2020-10-06 what is the best way for writing that code in short one?

```
declare val integer;
declare user_id_users integer:=0;
declare s integer;
BEGIN
user_id_users:=(select user_id from users where user_id=new.user_id ) ;
if ( user_id_users <> 0) then
s:=(select acc_type_id from users where user_id=new.user_id);
val:=(select validity from account_type where account_type_id=s);
update users set expiry_date= (select current_date +interval '1 month' * val where  user_id=user_id_users);
end if;
   return new;
END;
```

I have written the code for insert, but when I insert a new user, It would be in a loop and it shows a lot of similar errors continuously as below:

> SQL statement "update users set expiry_date= (select current_date +interval '1 month' * val where  user_id=user_id_users)" PL/pgSQL function acc_type_expiary() line 17 at SQL statement

Comment: No need for a select `update users set expiry_date = current_date + ...` I  don't really understand on which table that trigger is defined

Comment: trigger is on users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating things. You don't need multiple selects, you only need a single select to get the value from the account_type table. If the trigger is on the users table, there is no need to run an UPDATE.

Select the value, and assign it to the `new` record

```
DECLARE
   l_months integer;
BEGIN
  select at.validity
    into l_months 
  from account_type at 
  where at.account_type_id = new.acc_type_id;

  -- no UPDATE, just assign the value.
  new.expiry_date := current_date + (interval '1 month' * l_months);  

  return new;
END;
```

Instead of `(interval '1 month' * l_months)` you can also use `make_interval(months => l_months)`

This requires that the trigger is defined as `before update for each row`

Comment: Oh Thankssssss a lot, It worksssssssss I really appreciate you

Comment: @sargol: then you are probably not providing a value for `users.acc_type_id` during the insert

Comment: Thanks a lot it works .you were so helpful for me .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your update should read:

```
update users set expiry_date = (current_date + interval '1 month' * val) where user_id = user_id_users;
```

Comment: again:SQL statement "update users set expiary_date= (current_date +interval '1 month' * val) where  user_id=user_id_users"
PL/pgSQL function acc_type_expiary() line 17 at SQL statement